# Is there any way to ignore the parameter value from image URL?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to compare the below URL with the other one, but every time I hit the URL, the unique code (Highlighted in Bold) is generated. Is there any way to skip the unique code so I can compare the remaining data?

https://stagedesignerimages.net/UserPhoto/0e8a78b2-eea3-475e-b38c-b3ea2b606926/Photos/Output/Standard/**cdbd2a4a-8892-443c-8071-9fb27c9144ae-22-07-2022-05-13-17-01836.png**

Unique code: cdbd2a4a-8892-443c-8071-9fb27c9144ae-22-07-2022-05-13-17-01836.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just remove the file name from the path? You could even use a regular expression if you're afraid you'll remove too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.net.URI provides a nice [method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) that allows you to resolve a given String (parsed as URI) against it.

E.g.

```
URI parent = URI.create("https://stagedesignerimages.net/UserPhoto/0e8a78b2-eea3-475e-b38c-b3ea2b606926/Photos/Output/Standard/*cdbd2a4a-8892-443c-8071-9fb27c9144ae-22-07-2022-05-13-17-01836.png")
        .resolve(".");
```

results in URI `https://stagedesignerimages.net/UserPhoto/0e8a78b2-eea3-475e-b38c-b3ea2b606926/Photos/Output/Standard/`